# To prevent cron emails do I need to redirect output to /dev/null?

Tags: cron

My cron job

```
usr/local/bin/wp --user=cronuser --url=https://mysite.org --path=/srv/www/mysite.org/public_html civicrm api job.execute auth=0
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [is_error] => 0
    [version] => 3
    [count] => 1
    [values] => 1
)
```

Is there a way to prevent this output without redirecting to /dev/null ? I'd like to get an email if there is a problem.

clarification: I'm really asking how to stop the output (if there are no errors) from the wp-cli command for scheduling civicrm jobs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a cron question, not a CiviCRM question.  A good answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1396553/2832108.  In short: redirect your stdout to /dev/null, but not stderr.

Comment: But is there a way to make this command run quiet if there are no errors.  I'd like to see errors.  It seems like there is some sort of debug mode turned on.  And Is the output part of wp-cli or somehow from civicrm api?

Comment: @jon, IMO this is a CiviCRM issue and @onefiftyfour's instincts are right. UNIX tools are typically silent (or can be silent) in normal operation, and only generate output when there is an error state. CiviCRM lacks the `--quiet` switch which Xavier proposes below. See eg in [ESR's "17 UNIX Rules"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Eric_Raymond.E2.80.99s_17_Unix_Rules) the **Rule of Silence**. CiviCRM not following this leads to many CiviCRM installs routing cron output to `/dev/null`, an antipattern that means they don't see error output from CiviCRM when necessary.

Answer (score 3):

What I've done to fix this is create a bash script that executes the civicrm api command, captures the output to a variable, tests for the string [is_error] => 0, if there's no match, then it echos the output of the command.

Here's the script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

output=$(/usr/local/bin/wp --user=cronuser --url=https://mysite.org --path=/srv/www/mysite.org/public_html civicrm api job.execute auth=0)

### only print if error is not 0

if [[ $output != *"[is_error] => 0"* ]]
then
  echo "$output";
fi
```

Comment: We've expanded on very good idea into [civi_api_trap_errors.sh](https://github.com/twomice/misc/blob/master/civicrm/civi_api_trap_errors.sh), to which we pipe all civicrm cron job output, like so:
*/14 * * * * /usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/cv api job.execute --user=civicrm_cron --cwd=/var/www/domains/example.org/html 2>&1 | /usr/local/bin/civi_api_trap_errors.sh;

Answer (score 1):

So what you'd want is a "quiet" option that does only spit out a message if it's an error?

I'm not super sure what's the default on cron if there isn't any text, does it send an empty email?

it doesn't exist, but sounds like a good improvement. Do you have coding skills or resources to make it happen?

Comment: Cron only sends an email if there was output.  Yes, a quiet option would be great.  But I'm not sure if it's wp-cli creating the output or the civicrm command.

Comment: the output is from the api call, that generates an json in that case